# Verifying that a value is a root of a given polynomial in a Grafakos paper.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I apologize for the non-descript title, this one is difficult to describe.  I'm reading a paper by Loukas Grafakos dealing with the Hardy-Littlewood Maximal function.  There is an "easy calculation" near the end that I've struggled to prove.  Let $p > 1$ and let $p'$ satisfy $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{p'} = 1$.  We have a value $a$ that satisfies
$$
a = \frac{p}{p-1} \frac{\gamma^{1/p'} + 1}{\gamma + 1},
$$
where $\gamma$ is the unique positive solution of the equation
$$
\frac{p}{p-1} \frac{\gamma^{1/p'} + 1}{\gamma + 1} = \gamma^{-1/p}.
$$
The easy calculation to be done is that this value $a$ is the unique positive root of
$$
(p-1)x^p - p x^{p-1} - 1 = 0.
$$
Ignoring uniqueness, I am looking for guidance on showing this.  I believe the necessary calculations are just arithmetic, but plugging either of the first equations into the polynomial doesn't seem to work.  Thank you.

Comment: It's real.  By complex conjugate I mean that $p'$ satisfies $1/p + 1/p' = 1$.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both $a$ and $\gamma^{-1/p}$ are equal to the same expression, so $a = \gamma^{-1/p} \implies a^p = 1/\gamma$ and $ a^{p-1}=a^p / a = \gamma^{1/p-1}=\gamma^{-1/p'}$. Then:

$$
\require{cancel}
a = \frac{p}{p-1} \frac{\gamma^{1/p'} + 1}{\gamma + 1} = \frac{p}{p-1} \frac{1/a^{p-1}+1}{1/a^p + 1} = \frac{p}{p-1} \frac{a^p+a}{a^p+1}
\\ \implies\;\;\;\;(p-1)\,\cancel{a}\,(a^p+1) = p\,\cancel{a}\,(a^{p-1}+1)
\\ \iff\;\;\;\;(p-1)a^p + \bcancel{p} - 1 - p a^{p-1} - \bcancel{p} = 0
$$

Therefore $a$ is a root of $(p-1)x^p- p x^{p-1} - 1\,$, which has a unique positive root by [Descartes' rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) given that $p \gt 1\,$.

Comment: Wonderful!  Thank you for the help.